# Submit a form in the background automatically

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to create a Google Chrome extension that runs constantly in the background, even when Chrome windows are closed - this is what a `Background Page` is for, correct? Or should I be looking at something else?

Basically what I wish to do is have a `setTimeout()` load a page every 5 minutes and if its presented with a login page, automatically logs in with a given username and password, otherwise it does nothing.

This is simply to keep the session alive...

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Yes, this is possible using the [`background` permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html#bg), which causes Chrome to run your background page silently, even when no browser windows are open.

Comment: How would I do the loading of the page and logging in?